# Not able to show the data coming from Livedata to recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I have an edit text and a button. If I click on the button the data of the edit text gets inserted into my List which a live data. I want to show the items of the list in the recycler view but its not showing any data. I think the observer is not getting called as it is showing greyish (same as when we declare a variable or function and we don't use it) or may be there is something else happening.

This is the only activity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NoteAdapter.OnItemClicked {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var btnAdd: Button
    private lateinit var etNote: EditText
    lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btn_add)
        etNote = findViewById(R.id.et_note)

        val mAdapter = NoteAdapter(this, this)

        recyclerView.apply {
            adapter = mAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        }

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[MyViewModel::class.java]

        viewModel.allNotes.observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let {
                mAdapter.updateList(it)
            }
        })

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            addNote()
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(note: Notes) {
        viewModel.delete(note)
    }

    private fun addNote(){
        val note: String = etNote.text.toString()

        if(note.isNotBlank()) {
            viewModel.insert(Notes(note))
            Toast.makeText(this, "$note inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my adapter

```
class NoteAdapter(private val context: Context, private val clickListener: OnItemClicked) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private val allNotes = mutableListOf<Notes>()

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val tvNoteItem: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_note)
        val ivDelete: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_delete)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false)
        val viewHolder = MyViewHolder(view)

        viewHolder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener{
            clickListener.onClick(allNotes[viewHolder.adapterPosition])
        }

        return viewHolder
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentNote = allNotes[position]
        holder.apply {
            tvNoteItem.text = currentNote.note
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = allNotes.size

    interface OnItemClicked{
        fun onClick(note: Notes)
    }

    fun updateList(newList: List<Notes>){
        allNotes.clear()
        allNotes.addAll(newList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
data class Notes(val note: String) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id = 0
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface NotesDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertNote(note: Notes){  //Suspended means it will run it background thread

    }

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNotes(note: Notes){

    }

    @Query("Select * from notes_table order by id")
    fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Notes>>
}
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Notes::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class NoteDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun noteDao() : NotesDao

    companion object{

        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: NoteDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): NoteDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    NoteDatabase::class.java,
                    "notes_table"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is viewModel class

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: NotesRepository
    val allNotes : LiveData<List<Notes>>

    init {
        val dao = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).noteDao()
        repository = NotesRepository(dao)
        allNotes = repository.noteList
    }

    fun delete(note: Notes) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.delete(note)
    }

    fun insert(note: Notes) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(note)
    }
}
```

Here is my repository class

```
class NotesRepository(private val dao: NotesDao) {

    val noteList = dao.getAllNotes()

    suspend fun insert(note: Notes){
        dao.insertNote(note)
    }

    suspend fun delete(note: Notes){
        dao.deleteNotes(note)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your observer is fine. It's grey because you're using a verbose syntax and it is suggesting you make it more concise. Can you add your code for your Repository's `noteList`?

Comment: I can't spot any problems with the code you've posted so far. Could be a problem in your Activity or Fragment.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have added all my code. Please check now